# No indent the first paragraph of a LaTeX document

Tags: sectioning, indentation

In the standard LaTeX article class (and probably others as well), paragraph indentation follows standard American publishing norms of not indenting the first paragraph after a `\section{}` or `\subsection{}`.

I've redefined `\maketitle` in a LaTeX document and put the actual title left-aligned as the last line, fairly close to the actual text (kind of like this)

```
Author
Date

Title

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat.

    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 
esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint 
occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia 
deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Section title

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat.

    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 
esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint 
occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia 
deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

Since the title is left-aligned and so close to the text, I'd like the first paragraph of the document to not be indented, just like with the headings

```
...
Title

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat.

    Duis aute irure dolor...
...
```

I've attempted to use `\@afterindentfalse`, which is what the `\section` commands use, inside my renewed commands, but it doesn't work.

```
\makeatletter

\def\noindentation{\let\@afterindentfalse}

\newcommand{\mytitle}[1]{%
    \vskip 2em
    {\bf\sffamily\LARGE #1}
    \noindentation}

\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{
    \begin{flushleft}{

        % Author
        \@author \par 

        % Date
        \@date \par 

        % Title
        \mytitle{\@title}

    } \end{flushleft}
} 
\makeatother
```

By default the first paragraph in the article class is indented, so this question is applicable whether or not I renew `\maketitle`.

So, what's the best way to automatically not indent the first paragraph of the document?

Comment: To me it's not clear what you're doing. For example, do you have a \section command after the \maketitle? It would be useful if you could provide a minimal _working_ example.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have you tried using the `\noindent` command in your definition of `\maketitle`?

Normally when you put `\noindent` at the beginning of a paragraph, it prevents that paragraph from being indented. It may or may not work for your purposes. (For all I know it might just use `\@afterindentfalse` internally)

Comment: Yeah, that works, but I'm hoping to make it automatic, so I don't have to worry about manually adding that to the first paragraph...

Comment: Oh, yeah, I actually meant to suggest that you try `\noindent` in your definition of `\maketitle` :-/ I'll edit that for clarity.

Comment: `\noindent` will only work if it is placed *immediately* before the text that you want not to indent (with no blank lines in between). So adding it to the end of your definition of `\maketitle` will only work if you start the first paragraph immediately after the `\maketitle` command.

Comment: I had a feeling that was the case, but thanks for clarifying that, Anton.

Comment: I ended up doing this. I have a perl script that generates the LaTeX, so I just stuck in a \noindent.

Answer (score 17):

If you want all the paragraphs to have no indent, but a line skip instead, use `\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}`.

From a layout stand point, it seems like it should be an all-or-nothing proposition, either all are indented, or all use the line break to indicate a new paragraph.

Comment: Nah, it's not necessarily an all-or-nothing thing--plenty of books and articles do the first-paragraph-not-indented thing for stylistic purposes. It'd be a ton easier if that wasn't the case, though...

Comment: Thanks for the parskip package pointer. I might just use that instead if this turns out to be undoable.

Comment: your document is going to looks quite strange if some paragraphs are indented, while others are not, even if its after a heading... but that's just my 2 cents :D

Answer (score 7):

I believe problem has to do with grouping.  You have to call `\@afterindentfalse` at the outermost level (and it seems you also have to use `\@afterheading`).  For this reason making a general `\noindentation` macro may be difficult.

The following modification works for me.

```
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{
  \begin{flushleft}{
      % Author
      \@author \par
      % Date
      \@date \par 
      % Title
      \mytitle{\@title}
    }
  \end{flushleft}
  \aftergroup\@afterindentfalse
  \aftergroup\@afterheading
}
```

Comment: This answer's useful. Also important: those commands must be called in vertical mode, not in a paragraph, so in some contexts (not here) you need to issue `\par` before the first.

Answer (score 4):

The cleanest solution is probably to use `\noindent` in front of the first paragraph. You only have to do it *once*, so redefining `\maketitle` seems like more trouble than it's worth.

If you're determined to redefine `\maketitle` so that the first paragraph is not indented, then just redefining it to end with `\noindent` will **not** work if you have a blank line between `\maketitle` and the first paragraph (because the blank line causes TeX to enter vertical mode). Instead of using `\noindent`, you can use the combination `\@afterindentfalse\@afterheading`. In other words, the following should do what you want:

```
...
\maketitle
\makeatletter
  \@afterindentfalse
  \@afterheading
\makeatother

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
...
```

If you want to, you can redefine `\maketitle` to include `\@afterindentfalse\@afterheading` at the end.

However, it seems like adding `\@afterindentfalse\@afterheading` to the end of `\@maketitle` doesn't work. Some of the things that `\maketitle` does after it does `\@maketitle` must be messing it up.

Answer (score 3):

The [`titlesec` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) allows you to do this very neatly.

```
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1.5ex}{1.5ex}
```

The `*` version of `\titlespacing` command removes the initial indentation of the first line in a section.
The other arguments are for tuning the whitespace around the section title.